# How to decide optimum workflow size?

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow, optimization

What is the best practice to separate different activities for the same list over number of workflows ?

In a typical example, if I want to perform 5 different set of activities upon an item change on a list, one option is putting all 5 into the same workflow, perhaps separating them into different stages. Another extreme is having 5 workflows, one for each activity set. The former creates a large workflow, which is likely to take longer to complete, the latter creates perhaps too many workflows at once if multiple list items are edited at once. What is the recommended approach for optimizing number of workflows to use ?